# Vue.js links are not clickable, and Home component does not load by default

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Ok, I am JUST getting started with vue.js.  I've added a TypeScript vue.js project into an exiting Visual Studio 2017 solution. Out of the box that worked pretty well.

But now, I'm trying to do something that should be pretty simple... create some pages and navigate between them. I've found 3 or 4 tutorials but none of them match enough what I already have to make them adaptable, and I'm having a hard time finding what I need in vue.js's documentation.

Here's a screenshot of what my project looks like right now....

[image]

And here's the `App.vue` file:

[image]

And this is the router/index.js file:

[image]

With all of this, here's what is rendered in the browser:

[image]

This ALMOST correct except for two things:

1) The links for `Home` and `Time Sheet` are not rendered as clickable html links.  This is what they look like in dev tools:

[image]

2) I thought that the Home component would be loaded by default, but it's not.

So, two questions:

1) How fo I make the links clickable?

2) Why doesn't Home load by default?

**EDIT:**

Here's the main.ts file:

[image]

Comment: Could you post your `main.ts` file too?

Comment: @yuriy636... done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set up vue-router on your main.js file as well. here is an example:

```
import router from './router' 
 new Vue({  
   render: h => h(App),  
   router 
 }).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: ok, thanks!  I just posted a pic of what the main.ts file looks like right now. I'm going to try to adapt what you have here to what I already have.

Comment: On `import router from '.router'` I am getting: Could not find a declaration file for module '.router'

Comment: are you sure you have the right import path? It does not have to be exactly the way I imported it. Just be sure of your import path

Comment: forgive my ignorance... how does the path structure work?  What does the . in './router' mean?

Comment: Or could it be that I did not properly install the router modal?

Comment: Here is a full description of how imports work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import